# how to open a itunes link in uiwebview

Tags: uiwebview, itunes

Is it possible to load a app store link in uiwebview. I have tried to open it in uiwebview but it doesnt load in there. I dont want users to leave my app when they click on the url from my app. Is it possible?

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 6):

iTunes content does not have an "iTunes Preview" page on mobile - iOS automatically recognizes itunes.apple.com links and opens the store.

If you want to keep the user within your app, use SKStoreProductViewController to open the store to a specific piece of content.  After the user dismisses the sheet, they are still within your app.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html