# How to open https links in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl

https://www.google.co.in/

https://en-gb.facebook.com/login/

I can opened above links successfully... But below link not opened in webView why? How to solve this problem?

https://itunes.apple.com/in/developer/whatsapp-inc/id310634000?mt=8&uo=2

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
   webView.frame = self.view.frame;
   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]];
   [self.view addSubview:webView]; 
   NSLog(@"%@", self.urlString);
   // https://itunes.apple.com/in/developer/whatsapp-inc/id310634000?mt=8&uo=2   
 }
```

This self.urlString comes from server...

Comment: using itms:// instead of https://

Comment: Actually this is online data came from server (web services concept) , how can i do

Comment: i tried it's not working....

Comment: are you getting itunes links only from server?

Comment: i am getting itunes link from server  successfully, but it's not opened on webView....

Comment: itunes links are directed to appstore.

Comment: If you want to open itunes link i suggest you to use `SKStoreProductViewController ` It will open your itunes link in your app.

Comment: Is SKStoreProductViewController works only for itunes or any https links?

Comment: @Sunny can u send sample code na?

Comment: You should follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: I think it link your app to any itunes item only.

Comment: Please read [how to open a itunes link in uiwebview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14596339/3483725)

Answer (score 1):

From this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14596339/6438500).

Maybe for better user experience `itunes` links doesn't open in `UIWebView` as iTunes content does not have an "iTunes Preview" page on mobile - iOS automatically recognizes `itunes.apple.com` links and opens the store.

So if you want to open `itunes` link you should use `SKStoreProductViewController`. It opens you `itunes` item in your app.
Follow these links to use `SKStoreProductViewController`

[How to links to apps to app store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/6438500)

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController.h file create an outlet

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
```

In ViewController.m file `viewDidLoad`

```
_webview.delegate = self;

[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",URLSTRING FROM SEVER]]]];
```

Comment: This is my string comes from server ... https://itunes.apple.com/in/developer/whatsapp-inc/id310634000?mt=8&uo=2

Comment: already i tried to change https:// to http:// , but it redirected .....

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *fullURL = @"https://itunes.apple.com/in/developer/whatsapp-inc/id310634000?mt=8&uo=2";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```